# Finding more info on Python functions, 3 quick questions

Tags: python, pycharm

I am going over a [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html) the one where the following example is demonstrated:

```
>>> 'str'.strip() + 'ing'   #  <-  This is ok
```

In this example (as i understand it) `str` is a string, on which function `strip()` is called.

I would reasonably expect to find that function doing `>>> dir("abc")`. Indeed function is listed as  `'strip'`

**Question 1:** Why are some functions listed as `__name__` and others as `name`?

**Question 2:** I would like now to find more information about this function. When running `help("abc")` (expecting to get a man page on all functions that can be ran on string), `strip` is not listed. Why? Where can i find out more about particular function?

**Question 3:** Using [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) i would expect the following autocompletion to work and yet, i see nothing. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen the [online docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)?

Comment: For **Question 2** try `help(str)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Functions surrounded by double underscores are special functions that can be overridden to implement special behaviors. For example, the `__getitem__` function, when implemented in a class, allows indexed access to items in that class. (In other words, `a[5]` is equivalent in most contexts to `a.__getitem__(5)`). The underscores just signal that they're special, and require some special handling. (For example, don't invent your own.)
2. When you pass a string to `help`, it treats the string as a query. For example, `help('class')` brings up a bunch of information about classes. If you want the `help` text for string objects, do `help(str)` or `help('str')`.
3. I don't use PyCharm, so I can't help there.

Comment: Technically, *all* methods "implement special behaviours". I would say, rather, that under-under methods are called by Python itself from time to time, rather than being useful for users to call directly.

Comment: @lvc, we could quibble about what "special" means, I guess, but I don't care that much. I'm just echoing the language [from the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names); allowing "special syntax" seems like "special behavior" to me. (Just don't call it "magic"!)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `help("abc")` which gives help on abstract base classes, try `help(str)` which gives help on strings, including the *str.strip* method.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for 3**. Make sure you have Python Interpreter specified in **Settings | Project Interpreter**?

Here is what I get for your example:
[image: completion in PyCharm]